# split hex string with spaces into bytearray in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

i am new to Qt.
i am try to split hexa string with whitespaces for send to serial port

this is the code:

```
QByteArray ba;
QString sometext = ui->txtDataToSend->toPlainText();
QStringList query = sometext.split(QRegExp("\\s"));
ba.resize(query.size());
for (int i = 0; i < query.size();i++) {

   ba[i] =  ?????
}

serial->write(ba);
```

the split is ok but i dont know what should i put inside the for loop

please your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to split hex encoded data, simply use [`QByteArray::fromHex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromHex):

```
QString sometext = ui->txtDataToSend->toPlainText();
QByteArray ba = QByteArray::fromHex(sometext.toLatin1());
```

If you have invalid hex data, like one byte encoded with only one hex without first '0', or with more then two character, use your loop with [QString::toUInt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toUInt):

```
QByteArray ba;
QString sometext = ui->txtDataToSend->toPlainText();
QStringList query = sometext.split(QRegExp("\\s"));
ba.resize(query.size());
for (int i=0,j=0; i < query.size();i++) {
   bool ok;
   ba[j] = query[i].toUInt(&ok,16); // convert hex number to byte
   if(ok) j++; // if invalid number we will skip 
}
ba.resize(j);
serial->write(ba);
```

This will interpret hex string "12 3 4567 F0 F" same as "12 03 67 F0 0F".

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `QString::toAscii()` or `QString::toLatin1()` (Qt5)? It gives you a `QByteArray`.